# How to make the Material UI Tabs indicator change positions when using react-scroller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The MaterialUI Tabs component normally shows one tab content per view. The component I am working on, has all the tab components stacked and with the help of react-scroller, I am using the tabs to scroll the desired tab component into view. This is all working nicely, except the indicator is not changing positions.

react scroller has two props that allows for a function to trigger an event `onSetActive` and `onSetInactive`, as well as a prop to attach an `activeClass`, like below

```
<Link
  to={tab.label}
  id={tab.id}
  className={classes.tab} //styling classes
  spy={true} //watches for changes
  activeClass="active" //assigns a className when is clicked
  onSetActive={()=>handleOnSetActive()} //triggers on the item contains the active class
  onSetInactive={()=>handleOnSetInActive()}//triggers on the items that don't contain the active class
  containerId="containerElement" 
  onClick={()=> scrollToContent(tab.label, tab.id)}>
```

[**Here**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) is more info on react-scroller

When my page loads, the indicator is initially assigned to the first tab by default by material, but when I click to another tab, although I am navigating, the indicator doesn't move and when I inspect the console, the active class is not being reassigned to the current tab. How can I make this work?

I appreciate the help and here is a
[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tabs-scroller-1pwi2k) to play with. Thanks in advance

**EDIT** After reviewing a little more, I realized that it's not updating the `value` in the `medias.map()` function items. Using index doesn't work either. But value seems to be 0 (the original state value) for all items in the map. I can add value to the tabs array, but I cant add it to the data cause it is API driven. Is there a way maybe that I can pass the index to value? Before you ask, no, `value={index}` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it. It so happens that there were no issues with my logic per-se. The problem was with using the Link component. When I attributed the props directly to the Tab component, it all worked.

```
<Tab
    label={tab.label}
    key={index}
    to={tab.label}
    value={tab.value}
    id={tab.id}
    className={classes.tab}
    spy={true}
    smooth={true}
    isDynamic={true}
    spyThrottle={500}
    ignoreCancelEvents={false}
    containerId="containerElement"
    onClick={() => scrollToContent(tab.label, tab.id)}>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't let me delete the question because it has a bounty. Hopefully another admin can. Otherwise, see my [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-tabs-scroller-1pwi2k?file=/src/HomePage.js) withe the fixed functionality

Comment: No need to delete the question, but adding to your answer a fixed version of the code sandbox in your question would make this answer much more useful to others in the future.

Comment: I don't think the `spy`, `smooth`, `isDynamic`, `spyThrottle`, `ignoreCancelEvents`, and `containerId` props are having any effect since they don't mean anything to `Tab`. The call to `scrollToContent` in `onClick` is the part that is actually doing something.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just cleaned it up